# Nginx Module (Filebeat) getting data from another server B

Tags: nginx

I am trying to resolve the following case.

I have my ES, filebeat, logstash, and kibana installed and setup on Server A. 
But now I am trying to activate this "Nginx module" to monitor activities and logs from Server B. After I have activated the module and configured it, I notice it does not able to capture any data.

My logstash also did not received any form of index recorded to the ES.

I also found that there is a difference between ES and Nginx understanding the setting of Remote IP, ES = `remote_ip` whereas Nginx = `$http_x_real_ip`. 
In the case above, how can I make server B data can be presented to server A?

Second question, is this correct that these modules are needed in the passing of data? 
Nginx >> Filebeat >> Logstash >> ES >> Kibana

Does all these above are used and placed correctly? Is there any settings I need to do ?

When I check on " service filebeat status" It shows me some error msg.
-- `File is inactive: /var/log/mysql/error.log. Closing because close_inactive of 5m0s reached.`

Comment: setup.template:

     enabled: true
     name: "nginx_filebeat"
     pattern: "nginx_filebeat-*"

   output.elasticsearch:
     hosts: ["server_ip:9200"]
  
     #protocol: "https"
     username: "elastic"
    password: "************"
    index: "nginx-filebeat-%{[agent.version]}"
 
    setup.template.overwrite: true

May I know why it does not take into effect of the file name and pattern?

Comment: Anyone can help on this ?